# Issues in primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces

Can anybody tell me how to insert the filter/search option in footer part of datatable using primefaces?

Answer (score 0):

For search, take [the example in the PrimeFaces gallery](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) and change the `header` facet to `footer`:

```
<p:dataTable ...>

    <!-- snip -->

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

---

I don't *think* there's an easy (read: built-in) way to move the filter input to the footer.

Comment: Yes, there is no built-in way.

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. But I am able to apply this global filter on datatable(both in header and footer part) . But still not able to achieve column wise filter search by keeping filter textbox in footer part.